How to get Shield Block at level 1 on a non-human Kineticist?
I want to create an Air Kineticist in Society, with Bastion Dedication on level 2,to have a meaningful way of spending my reaction.
For Bastion however, you need Shield Block, and I can only see 2 ways to get that; the Versatile Human heritage and the General Training human ancestry feat.
Is there any way to get Bastion Dedication on a non-human?

I think the only option here is to take the dedication at level 4, after grabbing the general feat at 3. Given that this is for society play, there's no point in suggesting the arrangement I made with a GM in my home game (locking in the feat at 3 from character creation, since I was getting the benefits of the feat for free from the metal armor impulse anyway.)

Added more details to the title question since 'how to get shield block' is a much easier question than 'how to get shield block early with a specific class'

Not as a Kineticist.
As you've noted, the Shield Block general feat locks out Bastion Dedication until 4th level for most classes. The exceptions are Champions, Druids, Warpriest Clerics, Fighters and Inventors. These characters start with Shield Block at level 1 as a bonus feat, and can go into Bastion dedication immediately at level 2.
Anyone else has to either be a Human to get a bonus feat that way, or wait until level 4.

This was my conclusion too. Unfortunately, the 4th level Kineticist feats are much better than the ones on level 2, so Human it is

Mixed Human Heritage
One potential option for this from the Player Core would be to have a custom mixed ancestry heritage for humans off of your base ancestry:

Custom Mixed Heritage: You can
work with your GM to create a mixed
heritage for an ancestry other than elf
or orc. A custom mixed-ancestry heritage is
an uncommon heritage. Choose an ancestry
to tie to the heritage. You gain any traits of
that ancestry and a new trait for your
combined ancestry, similar to how
the aiuvarin heritage below grants
the “elf” and “aiuvarin” traits. You
also gain low-light vision if the ancestry
tied to the heritage has low-light vision or
darkvision. The heritage lets you select ancestry feats
for the chosen ancestry in addition to those from your base
ancestry. The aiuvarin and dromaar heritages both have
special feats, but a custom heritage will need you to work
with your GM to create or adapt some.

This is limited in Society play and might be a bit too human depending on your reasoning for the question, but otherwise with an appropriate boon this would allow you to select the human ancestry feat General Training to pick up Shield Block at level 1 as a non-human ancestry of any class.

Custom Mixed Heritages (page 82) - this requires too much GM overhead to make broadly accessible. The Organized Play team will look to create opportunities to create additional mixed heritages in the future.


It is 100% not allowed in society play. (Technically it’s “limited” meaning we’re likely to see some sort of boon or achievement reward to open up access for this eventually. But as of now, it’s not an option.)
